# Why didn't my page refresh when using location.reload()?

Tags: javascript, html, freemarker, page-refresh

I know this has been asked multiple times on here, but I would like some input.

The web app I'm working on displays a table from a database via Freemarker.  It includes a submit button to delete entries from that database.  The button works fine for sending requests, but I wanted to have it automatically refresh the page, to show the new table without that entry.  I tried this:

```
<form onsubmit="location.reload()" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/person/delete/${profile.id};">
<input type="submit" value="Delete"></form>
```

and this:

```
<form onsubmit="location.reload()" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/person/delete/${profile.id};">
<input type="submit" value="Delete"></form>
```

Neither had any affect.  Further research showed me that reload() will refresh the page from the cache, unless forceGet is set to true.  I did this for both methods, and saw no difference.  Then I thought that it was a case of the page refreshing before it could get the updated information from the server, so I had it wait 100 ms:

```
<script>
    function reloadPage() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
        }, 100)
    }
</script>
<form onsubmit="reloadPage()" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/person/delete/${profile.id};">
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete"></form>
```

This works, but I'd like to know if there is any insight on why the original methods wouldn't work.  Also, are there any suggestions on alternatives to my code?

Edit:

To clarify, the path http://localhost:8080/person/delete/${profile.id}; doesn't lead to a page; its meant to call the method in the method in the resource class that will run the delete method:

```
@POST
@Path("/delete/{id}")
public void deleteProfile(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    manager.deleteProfile(id);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using onclick on a button and then send a get request to that url to delete the item from your database. Because forms redirect to the url specified in action, and I'm not sure why your code even works.

Comment: shouldnt you use window.location.reload()?

Comment: @Ash No need. All main properties are derived to window. Even `window.location...` works because `window.window` exists, as you are actually accesing `window.window` xD

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I didnt know that thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your code works, it shouldn't. When submitting a form it will actually redirect you to the URL you specified in `action`, so reloading and redirecting at the same time is just not possible.

My suggestion is using a http request to delete the data. That would look like this:

```
<script>
    function deleteData(var id) {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                location.reload(); // request successfull, so reload
        }
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://localhost:8080/person/delete/"+id, true );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
    }
</script>
<button onclick="deleteData(${profile.id})">Delete</button>
```

Alternatively you can use your form (without the reloadPage()) and have the page at http://localhost:8080/person/delete/xy redirect back to this site.

Comment: Reload should be made when the AJAX request returns, not inline to it.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález That's why I used `false` in the `open()`-method, that way when `xmlHttp.send()` is blocking until the request is complete.

Comment: That's deprecated. Most browsers don't block on `send` anymore as converting async methods to sync is code smell (browser talking). Here more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

Comment: I actually didn't know that, thanks! Changed the answer to be asnyc.

Comment: Also, to clarify, there is no page at the url; the path is used by the method in the resource class to run the code.  Basically,  the path takes the id of the profile, passes it to the delete method in the resource class, which in turn uses the method defined in the DAO to manipulate the database.

Comment: Hi, did any answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Because onsubmit is called BEFORE the action is ran. The flow is this one:

- Submit form
- Call onSubmit events
- Run action if event is not prevented

So what is happening is this:

- Submit form
- Reload page

Action is never reached because you are reloading the page, hence stopping all the page logic. Is like closing a program and opening it again.

Your 100ms is a dirty workaround because altough it works for you, it may not work for anyone that cannot process the action before those 100ms. Imagine a slow device, slow network or slow something that will delay the action more than 100ms. It will reload the page before the action is ran.

What I don't understand is why don't you let the webpage do the reload for you. Natural form submits takes you to the action url, loading it, hence reloading the page if is the same URL.

Comment: But the action is reached; reloading the page manually in the browser shows the table with the entry deleted.  That tells me that the issue is on the front end, with the html displaying old info.  Also, I agree that the 100 ms timeout isn't a good workaround at all.

Comment: Maybe the action is reached because executes the "remaining" javascript while reloading. Note that you are working on localhost, so you have zero latency. If you add latency to operations I'm pretty sure that most of the times they won't work. Was a problem I had in one project with WebSockets, "onbeforeunload" and high latency networks actually. I'm talking about my experience on this, as I had exactly this problem, and was different on different browsers.

Comment: @SVill That's also up to the browser. Some browsers have the same process for everything and can keep the connection open while the page is reloading, others have a process for each page that reuses when you reload, and others will destroy the process and create a new one when you reload. Sum this to the variant latency users will have and you will not receive the same result each time.